# Netty 4 : reference count in wrapped buffer

Tags: netty

Netty 4.1.2.Final

I am using `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer` method to wrap more than one `ByteBuf`s, API doc is [here](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/Unpooled.html#wrappedBuffer(io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf...)).

```
public static ByteBuf wrappedBuffer(ByteBuf... buffers)
```

The doc says

> Reference count ownership of all variables is transfered to this method.

**I update the question so it is more clear.**

I need send more than one `ByteBuf`s to multiple connections at once. **I can't use `ChannelGroup`** because some of the clients works in long-polling mode which means the response has to be sent in next request whose channel is not ready at this moment.

Hence, I have the following data structure stores the connected channels

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Channel> channels 
  = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Channel>();
```

And I have a method to broadcast the ByteBuf to the channels

```
public static void broadcast(final long registrationID, final ByteBuf [] buffers){
  final ByteBuf wrappedBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buffers);
  for( Map.Entry<String, Channel> entry : channels.entrySet()){
    final Channel channel = entry.getValue();
    if( channel != null ){
        wrappedBuf.retain();

        boolean isLongPooling = channel.attr(TYPE).get();
        if( isLongPooling )
          Reply.send( channel, wrappedBuf); // add into a queue which will be pulled by client in next request
        else 
          channel.writeAndFlush(wrappedBuf); // real time client , send in current channel
    }
  }
  wrappedBuf.release();  
}
```

**The problem is that: If I have more than one real-time clients connected, only one of them receives the response even if all of then are written.**

It seems it is a problem caused by reference count?

Thank you

Comment: The reason is not reference count,  it is caused by some handle modifies the `ByteBuf`. Hence only the first connection receives.  The solution is to add `asReadOnly()` after ByteBuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... it means that the you need to call release() on the returned buffer.

Comment: If I need call `release()`,  it means the input `ByteBuf`s are retained? Otherwise why would I need call `release()` if no change to reference count?

Comment: Because if you wrap buffers you should call release() on the newly returned buffer and not on the buffers you just wrapped.

Comment: From my test, it does not work in that way. If I do not call "retain" of the original `ByteBuf`, `IllegalReferenceCountException` will occur.  If I call `retain` of the wrapped `ByteBuf`, it does not change the reference count of the underlayer `ByteBuf`.